# How can i add an icon to each dynamic item using OneLineIconListItem. My code gives TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I don't seem to understand the error, because if i remove icon as an arguement from OneLineIconListItem, it works but without the food icon

```
class FoodScreen(Screen):
    pass

class FoodApp(MDApp):
    image = StringProperty()
    meal = StringProperty()
    category = StringProperty()
    origin = StringProperty()
    ingre = StringProperty()
    source =StringProperty()
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        Window.size = (500,800)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_start(self):
        ingredient = self.root.ids['foods'].ids['list']
        url="https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php"
        respond = requests.get(url=url).json()
        icons = list(md_icons.keys())
        icon=icons[2193]
        for i in range(1,20):
            if respond['meals'][0][f'strIngredient{i}'] :
                l= OneLineIconListItem(text=respond['meals'][0][f'strIngredient{i}'],icon=icon)
                ingredient.add_widget(l)
 
FoodApp().run()
```

Still new to kivymd
.kv file:

```
ScreenManager:
    FoodScreen:
        id:foods
        name:"foods"

<FoodScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        ScrollView:
            pos_hint:{'top':.4}
            size_hint:1,.5
            MDList:
                id:list
```

Answer (score 0):

After much search and hint from @Xyanight,
First add:
`class ListItem(OneLineIconListItem): icon = StringProperty("food")`
and adjust the `on_start`method to
`for i in range(1,20): if respond['meals'][0][f'strIngredient{i}'] : l= ListItem(text=respond['meals'][0][f'strIngredient{i}'], icon=self.icon) ingredient.add_widget(l)`
add in the kv file:
`<ListItem>: IconLeftWidget: icon: app.icon`

where FoodApp class variable `icon =StringProperty()` and local variable `self.icon = icons[2193]`